# How to go about writing a java http / web robot app?

Tags: java, http, bots

I'm looking in to trying to build an application that will allow me to interact with specific elements of a web site, without going through a browser.

This is more a matter of general interest but for my prototype I am using the Guardian web site.

I want to log in, crawl through the content to find articles that can be commented on, and then display and allow the logged in user to comment on the articles.

I am a professional java developer but I've never really gone in to http development, and my search for resources that will help me with this project has not turned up much.

Firstly, I suppose I should ask, is this possible?

Secondly if so how would you for instance log in and post a comment to [This Article](http://www.guardian.co.uk/fashion/2013/may/27/what-wear-british-summer-holiday)

Comment: Often, we deal with specific programming questions, rather than referrals to tutorials. However, as a professional Java developer, you'll know you'll need some form of an API to communicate with the databases for the Guardian web site. That might be the first place to start looking.

Comment: @ChrisCooney as long as OP doesn't want to manually perform HTTP GET/POST on the site and parse results manually

Comment: @Chris Cooney - the problem with this is that I have no knowledge of HTTP and I don't even know if I would need to have, I searched for API's as a first stage, but only found "crawlers" that can download entire sites. You are correct about the lack of specificity in my question though. I'll amend to make the questions more specific to the problem.

Comment: @GlenLamb: First of all I suggest you a good read about HTTP POST and GET. Java code for making a post or a get is pretty trivial.Btw for speeding up you can use libraries such as apache httpclient and jsoup for parsing resulting HTML

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Selenium Webdriver: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

But please be good.  Don't make a comment spam robot.

Comment: That is absolutely not my intention, I hate those things. The truth is though that it annoys me that I see them all over the place and I don't know how to do it myself. You know, it's sort of a profession pride thing.

Comment: sure.  hope i did not offend.  your use case was just a bit suspect, that's all.  :)

Comment: I am a bit of a guardian commenting nut.